# Transferring ownership to function with std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am trying to learn how to use smart pointers and understand ownership. When I pass an `auto_ptr` to a function by value, the function takes exclusive ownership of that pointer. So when the function finishes up, it deletes the pointer that I passed to it.

However, I get a compile error when I try doing this with a `unique_ptr`, as if copy assignment is disabled for `unique_ptr`s. Passing a `unique_ptr` by reference does not seem to transfer ownership, it merely gives the function a reference to the `unique_ptr`.

How do I get `auto_ptr`'s behavior with passing ownership to function to work with `unique_ptr`s? I would appreciate a link to a detailed tutorial on `unique_ptr`, as so far the ones I've read seem to only talk about `auto_ptr` or talk about the smart pointers available with Boost and seem to ignore `unique_ptr` because `shared_ptr` covers it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> However, I get a compile error when I try doing this with a
>   unique_ptr, as if copy assignment is disabled for unique_ptrs.

It is. `unique_ptr` has one, and only one, owner. It cannot be copied because that would result in two owners. In order to pass it by value into another function, the original owner must relinquish ownership, using `std::move`.

In order to use `unique_ptr`, you must understand [move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/can-someone-please-explain-move-semantics-to-me).

`auto_ptr` is simply a hacky approximation to true move semantics that doesn't actually work. It's best to simply forget this class ever existed.

Comment: @DeadMG That is a fantastic linked answer. I'm still wondering about one thing though: What happens when the `unique_ptr` that was passed goes out of scope? Is it like deleting NULL?

Comment: @newprogrammer: Nothing. It owns no resource, so nothing happens.